# Disable split screen - shows " Full screen display"

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, split-screen

I used `android:resizeableActivity="false"` in mainfest inside application tag inorder to disable the split mode for my application ,

but when i open my application the below dialog is shown at the bottom of my application
[image]

on clicking "Full screen display" i get a dialog like below

[image]

the dialog says if i enable the full screen then my app will function abnormally, is there any alternative to disable split screen option.

Comment: According to docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window, `android:resizeableActivity="false"` is best way to disable split screen mode for applicaton.

Comment: @HeisenBrg so will there be any issue if i enable full sceen

Comment: Then you have to check that on real device. As my experience I think there is no problem by disabling, I am already tried in one of my project.

Comment: @HeisenBrg is there any way to not show "Full screen display"

Comment: On which device are you testing ?

Comment: Device name : Honor 7X, Model BND-AL10 , Android version : 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable full-screen support add to the AndroidManifest.xml under the  element

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

by this, the "Full screen display" will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

in your mainfest you need

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

for a Separate activity

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

for entire APP

```
<application 
    android:resizeableActivity="false">
    . . .
</application>
```